# fullRunTask with a non-default project in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I have several projects defined in `build.sbt` with different sources. I want to keep the root project as it is, with its own source set (and classpath), but add an sbt task to compile and run the non-default project.

Here's the (shortened) `build.sbt`:

```scala
lazy val root = project in file(".")

lazy val anotherModule = project in file("modules/another")

lazy val runAnother = taskKey[Unit]("Run a task from anotherModule")
fullRunTask(initialImport, Compile, "another.module.Main")
```

`another.module` is, in fact, in `modules/another/src` and so isn't included in the root project.

When `sbt runAnother` is run, it can't find `another.module` on the classpath.

I don't want the `root` project to depend on `anotherModule` because, except for this task, the code in there isn't required by the root project.

How do I run this task with the classpath of the specified module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`runner`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/3269eae533a534a00d1fd41cebffbcd3b4fba099/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Keys.scala#L264) could be used instead of `fullRunTask` like so

```
lazy val anotherModule = project in file("modules/another")

lazy val runAnother = taskKey[Unit]("Run task with the classpath of runAnother sub-project")
runAnother := {
  (runner in Compile).value.run(
    mainClass = "another.module.Main",
    classpath = (anotherModule / Compile / fullClasspath).value.files,
    options = Array[String](),
    log = streams.value.log
  )
}
```

Note how we access the classpath of `anotherModule` sub-project

```
classpath = (anotherModule / Compile / fullClasspath).value.files
```

Now `sbt runAnother` should be able to run `anotherModule` sub-project whilst in default `root` project.